# Multi-region viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We're working on a digital twin for a multi-national customer. The APS/Forge account is registered in the EU. Our users in the US report subpar performance, presumably because all model data is fetched from the Autodesk EMEA cloud frontends.

Is it possible to build a multi-region viewer without manually duplicating all model content to a separate US APS account?

Is this blog post still accurate and a derivative can only be created in one region? https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/data-management-and-model-derivative-regions

Or is my question completely irrelevant and Autodesk is replicating model data between regions and transparently routing users based on origin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main purpose of **regions** in our case is to enable companies to prevent their data from being stored outside the **region** they need to keep their data in (for e.g. contractual reasons).

If you need better performance when viewing 3d models, I'd suggest trying **SVF2** - that's much more optimized and shares resources across all models that may be distributed around the world. See https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/update-svf2-ga-new-streaming-web-format-forge-viewer-now-production-ready

You can also reach out to us on aps.help@autodesk.com regarding speed issues and our team can have a look.

Comment: Hi Adam. Thanks for your response. I did reach out to you guys and received an answer just yesterday: SVF2 model data is not bound to the APS account region and can be freely selected in the viewer application (`streamingV2_EU` vs. `streamingV2`). My assumption was incorrect and it should be straight forward to build a multi-region viewer.